# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_9$ is not the homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

We solved a similar question in class: $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is not the homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ because if $f \colon \mathbb{Z}_{15} \to \mathbb{Z_8}$ is a homomorphism, then  $|Im(f)|$ divides $15$ and since $\gcd (15, 8)=1$, the homomorphism is trivial.

I can't use this method here because $\gcd(9, 9)= 9.$

Comment: Hint: The order of the image of an element divides the order of the element.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have a homomorphism $G \to H$ between two groups of equal size. Then $H$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $G$, so we must have $G \cong H$ because $G$ is the only quotient of $G$ having the same number of elements of $H$.

So it remains to show that $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^2$ are not isomorphic.

Note that $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of order $9$, whereas $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^2$ does not. 
Alternatively, you can count the number of subgroups of order $3$.

Comment: Your answer answers the question, but it's backwards with respect to the OP. Minor point.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a surjective homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_9$.

From the isomorphism theorems, we will have that $( \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3) / \ker(\phi) \cong \mathbb{Z}_9$.  For this to hold,  the order of the quotient group on the left must match the order of $\mathbb{Z}_9$ on the right, which forces $\ker(\phi) = \{id\}$.

This is a contradiction because...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following theorem:

$\textit{Theorem}$ Let $G_{1}$ be homomorphic image of a group $G$. If $G_{1}$ contains an element of order n and $|G|$ is finite, then $G$ contains an element of order n.

The proof of the theorem can be found in Malik Mordeson Sen.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi\colon G\to G'$ is a homomorphism, then for every $g\in G$:
$$\phi(g^{o(g)})=\phi(e)=e'$$
But also:
$$\phi(g^{o(g)})=\phi(g)^{o(g)}$$
Therefore:
$$\phi(g)^{o(g)}=e'$$
whence:
$$o(\phi(g))\mid o(g) \tag1$$
In your case, the order of the elements of $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ is $1$ (just for $([0]_3, [0]_3)$ or $3$, whereas -for example- $[1]_9$ has order $9$. Since $9\nmid 1,3$, by $(1)$ $[1]_9$ cannot be the image of any element of $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ under a homomorphism, namely $\Bbb Z_9$ is not the homomorphic image of $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$.